# Where to put angle ending on right triangle, only using variables.

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, trigonometry, graphing-functions, triangles

Let's say I have a triangle ABC, with side lengths abc. I need to draw a line from the angle connecting the base (c) and hypotenuse (b). I don't know the real angle, but I know it's sin-1. I need to draw a line from that angle, to the opposite side (BC), but the angle at which the line is drawn must be half the angle mentioned, therefore 0.5(sin^-1 (a/c) ). Is there an expression that tells me where to put the endpoint of this line (on BC)?   
[[BTW: Please give answers in terms of or using ABC as vertices, and abc as side lengths of the two remaining vertices combined. aka: a is the side length of BC. b is the side lenght of AC. c is the side length of AB. Case matters!]]

One more question (might be repetitive): I need the **length** of the line AD (or A>Endpoint). How do I get this length AD?
[image: Visual Description]

Comment: Are you trying to draw the angle bisector of $\angle BAC$?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 : Yes, I am trying to bisect the angle of BAC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the [Angle Bisector theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem), we have the relationship $\dfrac{BD}{CD} = \dfrac{AB}{AC} = \dfrac{c}{b}$, where $D$ is the point on $BC$ such that $\overrightarrow{AD}$ bisects $\angle BAC$.

Add $1$ to both sides to get $\dfrac{BD}{CD}+1 = \dfrac{c}{b}+1$, i.e. $\dfrac{BD+CD}{CD} = \dfrac{b+c}{b}$.

Since $BD+CD = BC = a$, we get $\dfrac{a}{CD} = \dfrac{b+c}{b}$. Solve for $CD$ to get $CD = \dfrac{ab}{b+c}$.

This is enough information to tell you exactly where to place $D$ on $BC$.

You can plug this back into $BD+CD = a$ to get $BD = BC-CD = a-\dfrac{ab}{b+c} = \dfrac{ac}{b+c}$.

To get $AD$, apply Stewart's Theorem as done [here](https://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Length_of_Angle_Bisector) to get $AD = \sqrt{bc\left(1-\dfrac{a^2}{(b+c)^2}\right)}$

Note: The above formulas hold even if $\angle ACB \neq 90^{\circ}$.

Comment: thank you! but I do not understand how you "solve to get" BD=ac/(b+c). Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: and, @JimmyK4542, what is the **length** of line AD?

Answer (score 0):

If your endpoint is E and you know $\angle EAC=0.5 \arcsin (\frac ac)$, then $\tan EAC=\frac {EC}{AC}$ or $EC=AC \tan \left(0.5 \arcsin (\frac ac)\right)$

Comment: arcsin = inverse sine (right?)

Comment: what is the length of line AE? (thanks)

Comment: Yes, arcsin is inverse sine.  I had assumed C is a right angle because it is drawn that way, but I now see you didn't state that.  Is it known to be right?